# How to hide all fields at once in QGIS 1.7

Tags: qgis, fields-attributes, qgis-1

Is there a way to hide all the fields at once in QGIS 1.7?

I see where I can hide one field at a time but I would like a button which does it all at once.

Comment: Do you mean field attributes displayed in a layer? Or 'layers'?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

with the GUI no but with a small Python script run in the Python console you can:

```
from qgis.utils import iface
layer = iface.activeLayer()
indexes = layer.pendingAllAttributesList()
for i in indexes:
      layer.setEditType(i, QgsVectorLayer.Hidden)
```

Copy and paste the following into the QGIS Python console and it should hide all the attributes on the layer.

Comment: What is the preferred way to save this bit of code in the interface somewhere?  Or how easy is it to attach this to a ui button?  I'd like to give a go at contributing to the project

Comment: @Nathan W- Has there been any GUI updates to bulk hide/show in 2.4?  If not (for non-techies) what is the appropriate EditType to show the fields (opposite of QgsVectorLayer.Hidden)?

Comment: Never mind about the code... I figured it out.   To revert to the default setting, use: `layer.setEditType(i, QgsVectorLayer.TextEdit)`.  But is there a bulk on/off in the GUI?